# R How do I extract first row of each matrix within a list?

Tags: r, list, matrix, element

Say I have a list called mylist_1 with 2 matrices:

```
mylist_1

$region_1           
users   50  20  30
revenue 10000   3500    4000

$red            
users   20  20  60
revenue 5000    4000    10000
```

How do I extract the first row of each matrix into its own matrix?

i.e. output (first column here are rownames):

```
region_1    50  20  30
region_2    20  20  60
```

or the second row of each matrix?

```
region_1    10000   3500    4000
region_2    5000    4000    10000
```

Is there a way to reference the list/matrices to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Or,

```
lapply(mylist_1, `[`,1,)
lapply(mylist_1, `[`,2,)
```

Comment: @shadow.  I am not entirely sure about the reason.

Comment: I'm just about to ask a question about this odd behavior.

Comment: @shadow, that would be great

Comment: It's not odd behavior. `lapply` is not `sapply`.  They each have a different purpose.  `lapply` is to be applied over a list.  `sapply` only works on lists under specific conditions. It's all in the help file/

Comment: I like this, but it keeps it as a list (I want the output to be a matrix)

Comment: @shecode. thanks. then `sapply()` is the better option.

Comment: `do.call("rbind", lapply(mylist, "[", 2, ))`

Comment: Ok, remember to transpose!! Haha

Comment: @RichardScriven. Can you enlighten me as to where in the help file this is. I could not find it. Feel free to answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179109/different-behaviors-when-passing-empty-ellipsis-arguments

Comment: @RichardScriven - sapply should always work on a list. Whether you get sensible results depends on what you try to return.

Comment: @akrun is there a way to modified  ```lapply(mylist_1, `[`,1,)``` so you can extract instead of the first row the first cell (1,1)?

Comment: @Jonathan1234 if it is a matrix, then you can just do `lapply(mylist_1, `[`,1)`

Comment: @Jonathan1234 example is `my_list <- list(matrix(1:6, 2, 3), matrix(1:6, 2, 3))
> lapply(my_list, `[`, 1)`

Comment: @akrun and we do not have to use ``` "["```?

Comment: You can use both

Answer (score 7):

To extract the first row per matrix you can use:

```
lapply(mylist1, head, 1)
```

Or, if you want to `rbind` them:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, head, 1))
```

Or for (only) the second row per matrix:

```
lapply(lst, function(x) x[2,])
```

Comment: OR `t(sapply(mylist_1, "[", 1, TRUE))` and `t(sapply(mylist_1, "[", 2, TRUE))`

Comment: @shadow, good points! `lapply(lst, `[`, 2, TRUE)` should also work then :) (for the second row)