# different behaviors when passing empty ellipsis arguments

Tags: r, lapply

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25178684/2591234) brought up the question of how the ellipsis feature in `R` handles empty arguments. Apparently an empty argument in `...` works sometimes (see `lapply` version below) but not other times (see `sapply` version). Here's the example:

```
lst <- list(x=matrix(1))
lapply(lst, "[", 1, )
# $x
# [1] 1
sapply(lst, "[", 1, )
# Error in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : 
#   argument is missing, with no default
```

From what I can tell, `sapply` actually just reuses its `...` arguments when calling `lapply`. So I don't understand why `lapply` works but `sapply` doesn't. Can anybody explain this behavior.

In the `sapply` help it states that

> sapply(*, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE) is equivalent to lapply(*).

However, I get the same results as above for the following:

```
lapply(lst, "[", i=1, j=)
sapply(lst, "[", i=1, j=, simplify=FALSE, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
```

By the way, I know that just adding `TRUE` would solve the issue in this case, but I'm more interested in why there is a difference, not how to solve it. I'm actually more surprised that it works for the `lapply` case than that it doesn't for the `sapply` one.

Comment: I guess it's not specific to `sapply` but to any `lapply` wrapper: `(function(X, FUN, ...) lapply(X, FUN, ...))(lst, "[", 1, )`; Perhaps, it has to do with the "historical reasons" Note in `?lapply` while its wrappers have to evaluate their arguments?

Comment: have you looked at the source code for sapply and lapply?

Comment: @JamesTobin: I have looked at the R part of the source code. `sapply` really just calls `lapply` (at which point it fails) and then simplifies the results. `lapply` calls `.Internal(lapply(X, FUN))`, and I haven't looked at the source code of that. `lapply` also does not seem to use the `...` at all(?) But it seems that somehow between the `sapply` call and the `lapply` call the meaning of `...` changes.

Answer (score 1):

Because I am not a C master, at all, I can only show you what the differences are between how `sapply` and `lapply` are represented internally. And maybe someone else can build on this answer a little bit.

So for `sapply`: we'll look at https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/base/R/sapply.R

And for lapply: https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/base/R/lapply.R

This shows that although `sapply` calls `lapply` it then also calls `simplify2array` which could be one of the issues, but my intuition is telling me that this isn't the issue.

`lapply` ends up using `.Internal(lapply(X,FUN))` which ends up calling `do_lapply` within the C source code here: https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/91aaa43312da6b0e6906ef221fd7756dc0459843/src/main/apply.c

My guess is that because `sapply` inherently passes two parameters into `SEXP args` the `...` argument is trying to create the `SEXP args` of `sapply` with everything after `sapply(lst, "[",` and because it can't figure out what to do with either `1,` or `j=` before it gets to
`simplify=FALSE, USE.NAMES=FALSE`, it fails. Although that would just be my guess. Whereas `lapply` doesn't have the additional arguments being forced into `SEXP args` so it can handle `1,` or `j=` in a different way.

This post, [Understanding how .Internal C functions are handled in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663704/understanding-how-internal-c-functions-are-handled-in-r), does a very nice job explaining some of the nitty-gritty C stuff.

Hope this helps explain the differences to some degree, or at least can serve as a starting point for someone with greater R-devel skills.